# How to rebuild the Widget onpress of floatingactionbutton?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i'm trying to pull new data from firebase cloud firestore and rebuild the widget on onPress of floating action button. i'm not sure how to rebuild the whole widget. Tried to call getList from the onPressed and setState() but still not rebulding widget evening nameList was updated.

```
class MyList extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'test';
  @override
  _MyListState createState() => _MyListState();
}

class _MyListState extends State<MyList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('TEST'),),
      body: MainList(),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
          backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
          onPressed: () {
          }),
    );
  }
}

class MainList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MainListState createState() => _MainListState();
}

class _MainListState extends State<MainList> {
  List<Test> nameList = [];
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getList();
  }

  getList() async {
    final _name = await 
Firestore.instance.collection('test').getDocuments();
    nameList.clear();
    for (var name in _name.documents) {
      Test addName = new Test(
        name.data['name'],
      );
      nameList.add(addName);
      setState(() {});
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: nameList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            child: Text(nameList[index].name),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it is not rebuilding? Is the `ListView` not reflecting your firestore date?

Comment: the first time when the app build, it is working fine, everything load up. but what i am trying to do is rebuild the list when i press floating action button. i put setState in floatingactionbutton onPressed() and delete some record from firebase. but the list not rebuild when i press the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once a widget is created `initState` isn't called again. So your listview is still reflecting the old data.

You could `getList` in the `onPressed` which would then update your `nameList`. You could then pass this `nameList` to `MainList`.

```
class MyList extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'test';
  @override
  _MyListState createState() => _MyListState();
}

class _MyListState extends State<MyList> {
 List<Test> nameList = [];  

 getList() async {
    final _name = await 
Firestore.instance.collection('test').getDocuments();
    nameList.clear();
    for (var name in _name.documents) {
      Test addName = new Test(
        name.data['name'],
      );
      nameList.add(addName);
      setState(() {});
    }
  }  

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('TEST'),),
      body: MainList(nameList: nameList),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.refresh),
          backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
          onPressed: () {
             getList();
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Your `MainList` widget would then look like:

```
class MainList extends StatefulWidget {
  final List nameList;

  MainList({this.nameList});

  @override
  _MainListState createState() => _MainListState();
}

class _MainListState extends State<MainList> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: nameList.length,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            child: Text(nameList[index].name),
          );
        });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Learnt something new today.

Answer (score 0):

Just calling setState() is not enough. You'll have to tell Dart what you are going to set. Sample code :

```
setState ( ()=> nameList = _fetchedList ) ;
```

In the above code, the variable nameList is assigned **within** setState().

In your code, you've two options. 
Option 1 :

```
setState(() {
  nameList.clear();
  for (var name in _name.documents) {
      Test addName = new Test(
        name.data['name'],
      );
      nameList.add(addName);
    }      
});
```

Or option 2, better way, use for loop to add in the data in another list and use setState with one line as below :

```
List<Test> _fetchedList ;

  for (var name in _name.documents) {
      Test addName = new Test(
        name.data['name'],
      );
      _fetchedList.add(addName);
    }  

setState( ()=> nameList = _fetchedList ) ;
```